# JavaFX+Afterburner.fx access parent window from child

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javafx

I have a program with this window structure:

[image]

Where left side has buttons and green zone is different windows that change where user clic on a left button.

I have a main class (call Estructura) thats acts as control for main window except green panel. For green panel, I inject (thanks to afterburner.fx DI) correspond panel base on user button selection from left side. Injected panel has its own controller that is lazy thanks to DI Framework base on MVP.

```
public class EstructuraPresenter implements Initializable {

private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(EstructuraPresenter.class.getName());

@FXML
ToggleButton btnPlantillas, btnAlumnos, btnEstadisticas;
@FXML
BorderPane pEstructura; //Correspond to all window except green zone
@FXML 
StackPane pContenedor; //Green zone

//Injection of all child windows that i want to show in green zone
@Inject
private AlumnosView alumnosview;
@Inject
private PlantillasView plantillasview;
@Inject
private EstadisticasView estadisticasview;


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    //I set up green zone with alumnos panel so I call method whit request section to load
    cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");

    btnPlantillas.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        cambiarSeccion("Plantillas");
    });
    btnAlumnos.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
    });
    btnEstadisticas.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        cambiarSeccion("Estadisticas");
    });
}



//I pass to this method, name of window/panel that I like to load in green zone
public void cambiarSeccion(String nombreVentana) {
    try {
        //First, reset all buttons (so when user select an option and enter in case, I select option button making like effect as a selected)
        btnAlumnos.setSelected(false);
        btnPlantillas.setSelected(false);
        btnEstadisticas.setSelected(false);

        switch (nombreVentana) {
            case "Alumnos":
                if (btnAlumnos.isSelected() == false) {
                    sepTitulo.setVisible(true);
                    lbTitulo.setText("Alumnos");
                    btnAlumnos.setSelected(true);
                    //I need to do this check because for first time program load because green zone hasn't got any previous panel load 
                    if (pContenedor.getChildren().contains(alumnosview.getView())) {
                        pContenedor.getChildren().clear();
                        alumnosview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::add);
                    } else {
                        pContenedor.getChildren().add(alumnosview.getView());
                    }

                }
                break;
            case "Plantillas":
                if (btnPlantillas.isSelected() == false) {
                    sepTitulo.setVisible(true);
                    lbTitulo.setText("Plantillas");
                    btnPlantillas.setSelected(true);
                    pContenedor.getChildren().clear();
                    plantillasview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::add);
                }
                break;
            case "Estadisticas":
                if (btnEstadisticas.isSelected() == false) {
                    sepTitulo.setVisible(true);
                    lbTitulo.setText("Estadísticas");
                    btnEstadisticas.setSelected(true);
                    pContenedor.getChildren().clear();
                    estadisticasview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::add);
                }
                break;
            //There are more cases but I use same configuration like above examples...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
        new Dialogos().mostrarExcepcion(null, e);
    }
}
}
```

Well, when user clic on left button, panel is load ok in green zone. But problem I have is where user for example in green zone clic on a button/link... to load another panel (similiar to above description) but in that case I need to call from green panel controller to method cambiarSeccion() that is in EstructuraPresenter controller.

So for example, on case of user select estadisticas button (i hide in image, sorry I tried to simplified), that's is estadisticaspresenter controller:

```
public class EstadisticasPresenter implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(EstadisticasPresenter.class.getName());

    @FXML
    Hyperlink linkTotalAlumnos;

    @Inject
    private EstructuraView estructuraview;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        linkTotalAlumnos.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
             //This call apparently works, I debug and call to method cambiarSeccion happend but screen isn't update
            ((EstructuraPresenter) estructuraview.getPresenter()).cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
        });
    }
}
```

Where estadisticas window is loaded If I click on left buttons, works but If I clic on green load panel nothing happend. I resume problem in next image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [@josé-pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda) answer, finally I can link button/hyperlink from sub-window (green area) to main controller. The advantage of my solution is that I avoid use of boolean variables.

In `EstructuraPresenter` controller I add listeners to buttons from `EstadisticasPresenter`(which is the controller from one of the sub-window):

```
public class EstructuraPresenter implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(EstructuraPresenter.class.getName());

    @FXML
    ToggleButton btnAlumnos, btnEstadisticas;
    @FXML
    StackPane pContenedor;

    @Inject
    private AlumnosView alumnosview;
    @Inject
    private EstadisticasView estadisticasview;
    @Inject
    private DataModel datos;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
        ((EstadisticasPresenter) estadisticasview.getPresenter()).getLinkTotalAlumnos().setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            this.cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
        });

        //This call is from first time, where program starts to show by default Alumnos sub-window
        cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");

        btnAlumnos.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
        });
        btnEstadisticas.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            cambiarSeccion("Estadisticas");
        });
    }

    public void cambiarSeccion(String nombreVentana) {
        try {
            btnAlumnos.setSelected(false);
            btnEstadisticas.setSelected(false);

            switch (nombreVentana) {
                case "Alumnos":
                    if (btnAlumnos.isSelected() == false) {
                        sepTitulo.setVisible(true);
                        lbTitulo.setText("Alumnos");
                        btnAlumnos.setSelected(true);
                        alumnosview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::setAll);
                        pContenedor.getChildren().setAll(alumnosview.getView());
                    }
                    break;
                case "Estadisticas":
                    if (btnEstadisticas.isSelected() == false) {
                        sepTitulo.setVisible(true);
                        lbTitulo.setText("Estadísticas");
                        btnEstadisticas.setSelected(true);
                        estadisticasview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::setAll);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString());
            new Dialogos().mostrarExcepcion(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** In addition, I change `getChildren().clear()` && `getChildren().add()` to `getChildren().setAll()`; These prevents re-initializate controllers from each window that I put in green area.

estadisticasview.getViewAsync(pContenedor.getChildren()::setAll);

And in EstadisticasPresenter controller, I add getters from that controls that I want to user clic to go to another window (so when user clic on control, green area change with another window/pane).

```
public class EstadisticasPresenter implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(EstadisticasPresenter.class.getName());

    @FXML
    Hyperlink linkTotalAlumnos;

    @Inject
    private DataModel datamodel;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

    //Getters that I use in EstructuraPresenter controller to set up event handlers
    public Hyperlink getLinkTotalAlumnos() {
        return linkTotalAlumnos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice you get it working. But note you are exposing a control. The properties approach avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion your approach has one problem: When you call in any of your children presenters

```
((EstructuraPresenter) estructuraview.getPresenter())
     .cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
```

`estructuraview.getPresenter()` is actually creating a new instance of the main presenter.

This means that `EstructuraPresenter.initialize()` is being called again when you click on the hyperlink, and you have two calls to `cambiarSeccion()` (one from `Initialize`, one from the action), that add the children to the new instance, not to the old one, which is the one you see. That's why you don't see any change!

I'd suggest a different approach: Let the main presenter listen to changes in some properties on their childrens.

For example, add a boolean property to notify a click on the hyperlink:

```
public class EstadisticasPresenter implements Initializable {

    @FXML Hyperlink linkTotalAlumnos;

    private final BooleanProperty link = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    public boolean isLink() { return link.get(); }
    public void setLink(boolean value) { link.set(value); }
    public BooleanProperty linkProperty() { return link; }

    @Override public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        linkTotalAlumnos.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            link.set(true);
        });
    }
}
```

while on the main presenter:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    ...

    EstadisticasPresenter estadisticas = 
        (EstadisticasPresenter)estadisticasview.getPresenter();

    estadisticas.linkProperty().addListener((ob,b,b1)->{
        if(b1){
            cambiarSeccion("Alumnos");
            // reset link property
            estadisticas.setLink(false);
        }
    });
}
```

As a side note, instead of `clear()` and `add`, I'd use `pContenedor.getChildren().setAll(<view>);` since you only show one child at a time.